# What is Exponentiation definition and how it explains the base to power 0 is 1?

Tags: definition, exponentiation

I tried to understand exponentiation, but I can't understand that why any base raised to the power of 0 becomes 1.

As per Wikipedia the definition of b raise to power n is multiplications of base n times. Shouldn't it make more sense if we say a unit quantity is increased/decreased by base n times. If not then how would you explain anything raise to power 0 as 1 in layman/practical terms, like say counting bananas.

Addition: By increase decrease I mean multiplied and divided.  And please help me understand not by math formulas, as I am trying to imagine it in real world scenarios.

Comment: We just define $b^0$ to be $1$ so that our exponent rule $b^m b^n = b^{m+n}$ remains true. If that rule is going to be true, then $b^0 b^n$ should be equal to $b^n$, and that only happens if $b^0 = 1$.

Comment: thanks, can you please help with some real world example too..

Comment: @Dapu gave you real world examples!!! Just replace the variables with integers of your choice.

Comment: That's more of mathematical derivation.

Comment: The article [Wheat and chessboard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_and_chessboard_problem) may be one example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mathematics there is something called " recursive definition ".
Just as the name states, you define "sequences " recursively.
So lets motivate the idea behind the notion of taking, lets say a number to an arbitrary power ( in this case to the power of a natural number ).
What you are actually doing is : take an arbitrary "number" lets call it $a$, define $a^0$ as $1$ ( more generally you define it to be the "neutral element", with respect to the given (binary) operation (which lets say we assume to be associative as well), if there is any).
Then assume inductively that you have already defined what $a^n$ is for a given $n$ where n denotes a natural number, and then define $a^{n+1}$ to be $a^{n}$ times $a$. What do i mean by times. I did not give you the exact operation for which we have defined this notion, so you could just exchange it with lets say multiplication or addition ( for real numbers or rationals, etc., or any set equipped with a binary operation, which is associative and has a neutral element).
(!So in conclusion we could just say that this is a convention in mathematics.)( as one is not always interested in real world applications)

Comment: I see, so a presumption of a⁰ to be 1 is unity and further recursively we propagate it as "times" then shouldn't that unity, or as you call it "neutral number" be a part of definition? Instead of saying thats its just the multiple/times of arbitrary number?

Comment: I chose this as correct as it was closest to what I was looking for in terms of definition. I wish I had a more.specific.answer. All answers were great, and perfect in explaining though. Thanks for your view, it helped me in concluding an answer to my question well.

Answer (score 1):

NO, "the number $b$ multiplied by itself $n$ times" is the definition of $b^n$ *if* $n$ is a positive integer; for other $n$ we need a different definition.

First thing to note about definitions is we *can* make any definition that we want; the only question is is it useful. There's no *mathematical* problem with the definition $$b^n=17$$ for all $b$ and $n$, but it would make exponentiation sort of useless.

So. How do we want to define $b^0$? We note that if $n$ and $m$ are both positive integers then $$b^{n+m}=b^nb^m\quad(*).$$That's a useful thing, so we try to preserve it when we extend the definition to $n=0$. Think about it for a second; defining $b^0=1$ is the only way to get $(*)$ to work for $n\ge0$.

Similarly for why we define $b^{-n}=1/b^n$.

Comment: b^n = 17 can be said as, a bag's quantity becomes 17 if we multiply it by b n times.